# How to dynamically track width/height of div in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, resize

I need a help with my work task: I have some **div** block with following styles:

```
.main-div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And some React Component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState();
  const [height, setHeight] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="main-div">
     <p>Block width: {width}, height: {height} </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can I get dynamically width/height of resizing **div**? I mean i have to keep track of the block dimension in the process of resizing.

Comment: For some reason I can't use thee answer below, I found [this](https://blog.sethcorker.com/resize-observer-api/) and it works! Give it a try...

Answer (score 17):

You could combine `ResizeObserver`, `useEffect`, and `useRef`:

- `ResizeObserver` allows you to observe a HTML element and to execute an event handler every time it gets resized;
- `useEffect` is executed right after the component mounted, so it is the right place to attach the observer to your div, and to disconnect it when the component is going to unmount via the returned function;
- `useRef` creates a reference through to a child.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState();
  const [height, setHeight] = useState();

  // useRef allows us to "store" the div in a constant, 
  // and to access it via observedDiv.current
  const observedDiv = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!observedDiv.current) {
      // we do not initialize the observer unless the ref has
      // been assigned
      return;
    }

    // we also instantiate the resizeObserver and we pass
    // the event handler to the constructor
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      if(observedDiv.current.offsetWidth !== width) {
        setWidth(observedDiv.current.offsetWidth); 
      }
      if(observedDiv.current.offsetHeight !== height) {
        setHeight(observedDiv.current.offsetHeight);
      }
    });
    
    // the code in useEffect will be executed when the component
    // has mounted, so we are certain observedDiv.current will contain
    // the div we want to observe
    resizeObserver.observe(observedDiv.current);


    // if useEffect returns a function, it is called right before the
    // component unmounts, so it is the right place to stop observing
    // the div
    return function cleanup() {
      resizeObserver.disconnect();
    }
  },
  // only update the effect if the ref element changed
  [observedDiv.current])

  return (
    <div className="main-div" ref={observedDiv}>
     <p>Block width: {width}, height: {height} </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

### Sources

1. ResizeObserver:

   - [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API)
   - [Browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/resizeobserver)
2. [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)
3. [useRef hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: Thanks a lot, albjerto! It work's very well for me!

Comment: @AdamBess instead of comment, you should accept the answer!